# Unity - plain material colour darker than expected

Tags: unity, materials, color

I want to add to scene object without textures, only plain material, here is my import flow:

I create object in Sketch and export to SVG:

[image]

Then I import SVG to blender (Material do not use nodes, has plain color #96DFE4) and export it to FBX.

Then I import FBX to unity, as you can see material colour is much darker than SVG created:

[image]

The only Lighting source I use is Ambient with colour white and Intensity 0.

How to render object with exactly same material colour as SVG? I don't want any shadows etc, just plain color.

Comment: What Unity version & pipeline do you use? You could use `Unlit` shader to make the material not use any lighting, or you could create your own shader and just copy and paste the texture itself as is.

Answer (score 2):

Default imported materials are not exactly what you'd want to have there. Create new material with `Unlit/Texture` shader, add your texture to it and apply material to model.